# problem on products in category theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $C$ be the category of torsion abelian groups. (1) How do you prove that products are representable in $C$? (2) Could you also please give me an example where the product in $C$ is not isomorphic to the product in the category of abelian groups?

Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think that there is such an example? Is this homework? Also, you mean arbitrary products, or just products of two objects?

Comment: Yes, professor told us there are exaples like that, and we need to find one.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that for finite product the usual product works. For infinite products it is no longer true: for instance, $\prod_n {\bf Z}/n{\bf Z}$ in the usual sense is not a torsion group (the element $(1,1,\ldots)$ is not torsion, for instance), so if the product exists within $C$, it is necessarily distinct from the product in $\textrm {Grp}$, so if you show the first part, the second is immediate.

Now, to find the true product, notice that for any abelian group $A$, the set $A_T$ of torsion elements of $A$ is a subgroup. Try to show that $(\prod_i A_i)_T$ is the product of $A_i$ in $C$ (it should help to notice that the range of any morphism in $C$ into $\prod_i A_i$ is actually contained in $(\prod_i A_i)_T$).